# Access Denied to any folder, C#

Tags: c#, file

Getting this strange error.

In C#, I write to a file (txt)  whose location I provide at run-time.

The problem is that whatever location I provide, It returns an error: Access to "..path.." is denied.

I checked the permissions, but the required permissions are set.

My code snippet

```
folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

StreamWriter path = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
.
.
.
```

Any known issues or something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass a file name to StreamWriter. It looks as if you're passing a folder name.

Comment: Henrik is right. You should use an OpenFileDialog and the FileName property.